# .rmarkdown file, blogdown and in window preview for RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

I have been using *.Rmarkdown* files to create blog posts in R blogdown. The output of chunk of codes in *.Rmarkdown* documents are printed in the console and not in the document. 
If instead I create a *.rmd* file, then previews are in window. RStudio Global options are set to show preview in window for RMarkdown documents.
Is this an expected behavior of *.rmarkdown* files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The differences between `.Rmarkdown` and `.Rmd` is explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html). The most relevant quote being:

> In this book, we usually mean .Rmd files when we say “R Markdown documents,” which are compiled to .html by default. However, there is another type of R Markdown document with the filename extension .Rmarkdown. Such R Markdown documents are compiled to Markdown documents with the extension .markdown, which will be processed by Hugo instead of Pandoc.

More specific differences are explained in the book linked above.

Comment: Thank you Emi. Yes that book is a great resource for using blogdown. I do indeed prefer .rmarkdown files because the output is cleaner. However in the book (and in a websearch) I have not found any insight about different behavior of the 2 type of  file when printing the output of chunks (in the windows  vs console  before rendering the website).

Comment: @c1au61o_HH They shouldn't have the different behaviors you described (which was surprising to me). You need to tell us the exact steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Here a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MObuqF9CXzhPR_EV8dw5izfSO8crLg31) to a folder with my diagnostic report and 2 screenshots

Comment: ... I create a post using * blogdown:::new_post_addin()* and I select *.rmarkdown* file. The theme used does not seem to have an impact on this. I have only tried on MacOs and not on Windows. Thanks @YihuiXie.

Comment: @c1au61o_HH The only official way to preview a blogdown website is `blogdown::serve_site()`. Per documentation at https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html, please do not click the Knit button or any other buttons in RStudio.

Comment: @YihuiXie I see. I tried to create a website using that workflow (and avoiding  RStudio buttons). I have also created a post by console but I had the same problem when I run chunks of code for .Rmarkdown files. I just want to clarify that when I preview the site or render and deploy  it, it does look as expected (with figures and outputs. thanks!